# Set default image to CloudinaryField in Model

Tags: django, cloudinary

I have recently started using Cloudinary for media storage. 
I have a Profile model with image and cover image fields

### Without Cloudinary

Before changing to cloudinary media storage the model looked like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # setup without Cloudinary
    image = models.ImageField(default='profile_image/default.jpg', upload_to='profile_image', blank=False)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(default='cover_image/default.jpg', upload_to='cover_image', blank=False)
```

It allowed me to set default image for both fields.

### With Cloudinary

Now, after adding Cloudinary, it looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # setup with Cloudinary
    image = CloudinaryField('image')
    cover_image = CloudinaryField('cover_image')
```

I want to be able to set default images for both fields.

Here are relevant libraries' versions

```
Django==2.1.5
cloudinary==1.17.0
django-cloudinary-storage==0.2.3
olefile==0.46
cloudinary-cli==0.3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloudinary now supports delivering default images when a requested image does not exist.

Assuming a case where you want a default image displayed in a page, **I have limited knowledge on whether you can do it from the model**, you can implement this functionality in the view that renders that page e.g

```
CloudinaryImage("if_set_image.jpg").image(transformation=[
'default_image': "default_image.png"
])
```

For more information read this [article](https://cloudinary.com/blog/placeholder_images_and_gravatar_integration_with_cloudinary) or the [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformation_reference#default_image_parameter)

Given that you need to work with cloudinary, you can also consider retaining the default django provided ImageField (hence easily set the default option) and use `cloudinary.uploader.upload("my_image.jpg")` to upload your images to cloudinary in your view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's of much help